# C++ build error using librealsense in ubuntu

Tags: c++, realsense

I installed `librealsense` from the source. It was installed and build successfully.

When I tried to run the sample project ([rs-hello-realsense](https://dev.intelrealsense.com/docs/rs-hello-realsense)) I have found the build error.

```
/usr/local/include/librealsense2/hpp/rs_types.hpp:90: undefined reference to `rs2_get_error_message'
/usr/local/include/librealsense2/hpp/rs_types.hpp:92: undefined reference to `rs2_get_failed_function'
/usr/local/include/librealsense2/hpp/rs_types.hpp:92: undefined reference to `rs2_get_failed_function'
```

Same kind of error from a different type of build.

```
CMakeFiles/rs-hello-realsense.dir/rs-hello-realsense.cpp.o: In function `rs2::error::error(rs2_error*)':
rs-hello-realsense.cpp:(.text._ZN3rs25errorC2EP9rs2_error[_ZN3rs25errorC5EP9rs2_error]+0x2e): undefined reference to `rs2_get_error_message'
rs-hello-realsense.cpp:(.text._ZN3rs25errorC2EP9rs2_error[_ZN3rs25errorC5EP9rs2_error]+0x73): undefined reference to `rs2_get_failed_function'
```

Comment: Did you link the library?

Comment: Where do I need to link the library? When it was built it already builds in /use/local/ and I can use by include '#include <librealsense2/rs.hpp>'  isn't it?

Comment: The build  process contains a compile step and linker step. In the compile step the headers are added to the compile unit. In the linker step the libraries are linked into your artifact. You need linker flags like `-lLIBRARY`, probably something like `-lrealsense2`. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, get it. Need to add a couple of lines in `CMakeList.txt`.
Which linked the libraries in the project.

```
find_package(realsense2 2.29.0)
target_link_libraries(rs-hello-realsense ${DEPENDENCIES} ${realsense2_LIBRARY})
```

OR

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${realsense2_LIBRARY})
```

Other than all other properties of CMake File will be same